# Howto get URL Facade in Lumen Blade Template?

Tags: laravel-blade, lumen

In a Lumen application where I'd actived Facade ($app->withFacades() in app's bootstrap) I could not use URL class in Blase template.

```
{{ URL::previous() }}
```

throw a PHP Fatal error: **Class 'URL' not found** in xxxx/storage/framework/views/8e6123...

I need it for the form cancel button.

What am I missing ?
Thanks

**Answer**: with Lumen the use of `app('url')` or `Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL` in Blade template is not enough because the class `Laravel\Lumen\Routing\UrlGenerator` is pretty stripped with only `full()`, `current()`, `route()` and `to()` methods. Eg. to get the previous (referer) url we have to use the long way: `app('request')->headers->get('referer')` or use JavaScript to redirect back

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no alias set up for the URL Facade by default. You either have to do that manually by adding this to `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL', 'URL');
```

Or you can use `app('url')`:

```
{{ app('url')->previous() }}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
The "app('url')" works fine but it has not a previous() method. 
The class Laravel\Lumen\Routing\UrlGenerator has only methods full(), current(), route() and to().

Comment: Ah yes. The routing classes in Lumen are pretty stripped down... You could use `app('request')->headers->get('referer')` or use JavaScript to redirect back.